# Add a new polygon to an existing shapefile from WKT in QGIS

Tags: qgis, shapefile, pyqgis, geometry, features

I have a layer of polygons in QGIS;
I want to add programmatically (PyQGIS) a new polygon to this layer using WKT.
Example:

```
   mywkt = POLYGON ((522762 376413 0,530635 368671 0,522237 353713 0,522762 376413 0))
```

I want to add this polygon to my layer.

I try this :

```
layer.startEditing()
geom = QgsGeometry()
geom = QgsGeometry.fromWkt(mywkt)
feat = QgsFeature()
feat.setGeometry(geom)
layer.dataProvider().addFeatures([feat])
layer.updateExtents()
layer.reload()
```

Answer (score 1):

You should express the WKT as a string:

```
mywkt = 'POLYGON ((522762 376413 0,530635 368671 0,522237 353713 0,522762 376413 0))'
```

for avoiding receiving an *invalid syntax* error.

Then, you should use `commitChanges()` for applying the changes to the layer.

With this slight edit to your code, you should be able to add the `mywkt` feature to your original shapefile:

```
layer = iface.activeLayer() # load the layer as you want
mywkt = 'POLYGON ((522762 376413 0,530635 368671 0,522237 353713 0,522762 376413 0))'
layer.startEditing()
geom = QgsGeometry.fromWkt(mywkt)
feat = QgsFeature()
feat.setGeometry(geom)
layer.dataProvider().addFeatures([feat])
layer.commitChanges()
```